# Error Pivot pandas tables celuas mescladas

Tags: python, pandas

Olá,
Tenho uma tabela no pandas e preciso transformar, acredito que usando o pivot, a partir de uma certa coluna

```
 Month  Codigo       COD 1       COD 2
 0      NaN  Date 1  07/05/2018  01/01/2019
 1      NaN  Date 2         NaN         NaN
 2  05/2018     0.9         0.9         NaN
 3  06/2018       1           1         NaN
 4  07/2018       1           1         NaN
```

Gostaria que essa tabe tivesse o seguinte output

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja tentei o codigo

```
 pd.pivot_table(all_data, values = 'COD 1', index=['Codigo'], columns = 'Month').reset_index()
```

Mas retorna o seguinte erro:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Esse é o link do meu excel, caso queiram dar uma olhada

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoDYwrtLrltJoF-fmNEAFX755uuu?e=1Jam2o

Comment: Coloquei o link, obrigado

Comment: vc só usa `values` quando precisa fazer algum tipo de agregação. Não precisa no seu caso

Comment: Mas como eu faço o comando? pois tentei remover e estou com erro ainda, é simplesmente remover values? pode por favor me dar um exemplo?
Removendo values, o erro é o mesmo
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate